# Compute the norm of $T$.

Tags: functional-analysis

I need some help with this problem:

**Let be $X=C([0,1])$ with te uniform norm (the max-norm). We define $T:X \longrightarrow X$ as $T(f)(x)=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} f(t^2)dt$. Compute $||T||=\sup\{||Tx||:||x||\leq 1\}$.**

I proved that $||T|| \leq 1$, but I'm trying to show that $||T|| \geq 1$ in order to prove that $||T||=1$, but I don't arrive to the solution. Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x)$ to be the constant function $1$ on $[0,1]$. Then $||f||=||T(f)||=1$, and so $||T||\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the constant function $1$. Then

$$T(f)(x)=x$$

for all $x \in [0,1]$

This gives

$$||T(f)||=1= ||f||.$$